# .htaccess - mod_rewrite condition for a filepath with a wildcard folder in the middle?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I essentially want to be able to go through folders within a certain folder and look for a match. I think an example is the easiest way to explain it:

I want to be able to access a file at <strike>`domain.com/css/style.css`</strike>

Or even  `domain.com/[modulename]/css/style.css` (which might help keep things more organized, now that I think of it)

But the file is in `/application/modules/[modulename]/public/css/style.css` and the [modulename] is potentially different each time.

I have `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/modules/$1 -f` but that won't work unless I use the url `/[modulename]/public/css/style.css` - how could I make it look for a wildcard in the middle of the path?

**Edit:** On second thought, it would have to be `domain.com[modulename]/css/style.css` because there might be more than one `style.css` in the entire site.

Comment: Ideally, I'd have something like `/application/modules/$1/public/$2` - but I'm not the best at mod_rewrite

Comment: The main issue here is the dynamic module name folder how do u know a given css file belongs to that folder if they have the same name in multiple folders ? You can however, get the file name with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/css/(.*\.css)$`

Comment: Given that you what that setup this might work `RewriteRule ^(.*)/css/(.*\.css)$ /application/modules/$1/public/css/$2 [L]`

Comment: @Prix well I need it for more than just css - there may be js, pdfs, images, etc - really anything. And I edited the question so that the url request will need the module name, eliminating the possibility that it'll have files with the same names

Comment: @Prix also also, it's one of two RewriteConds, so the one-line RewriteRule won't cut it :P

Comment: Well that really depends on how "everything" will be structured if you cannot track how it will be structured then you won't be able to come up with a good rule to redirect it. But given that it will be something like `module_name_as_folder/file_type_as_folder/filename.extension` you could try something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*/.*)$ /application/modules/$1/public/$2 [L]` this would take any file with the previous folder. **You should consider updating your question with your `folder/files` structure and how you want it redirect instead.**

Comment: `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/application/modules/$1` you cannot use the results on RewriteCond's left hand like that it won't work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

After working on it for five hours today, I got it working:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application/modules/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(.*)$ /application/modules/$1/public/$2
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [NC,L]
```